# how to link chatbot html file to a clickable image or button

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Say I have pre define **code** in nodejs of chat application.I want to open that as a chat window in lower right corner of my window. I included that html file in my by inclusion parameter but it wont run.

Comment: Define div that will have position fixed in the bottom corner, use jquery Toggle() to make it open up, and apply your design and nodejs code inside the div.

Comment: What about including your chatbot app wiht iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a float button on the footer then use jQuery to open and close chat box using the id.

Comment: Your answer needs to be a bit clearer, please provide an example of code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to implement what you're aiming for.

1. First I'm creating an HTML file, "Index.html". This file is the parent webpage that will display the chat box at the bottom right.

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id = "container-chatbox"></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script >

            const url = `./ChatBox.html`;//URL to your Node.js App

            // Render URL here
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    //Something to do before sending the request
                    console.log("Sending Request");
                    return true;
                },
                success: function(res) 
                {
                    //After receiving data
                    //ie. the chat box
                    console.log(res)
                    $("#container-chatbox").html(res);
                }
            });
        </script>    
    </body>

</html>
```

2. "ChatBox.html", is your Node.js chatbox entry point. I'm just displaying a "Hello Frnd!" message here.

`ChatBox.html`

```
<!-- This is your chatbox element -->

<div style="  
position: fixed;
bottom: 50px;
right: 50px;
height: 250px;
background-color: rgb(237, 239, 244);
width: 300px;
">
<!-- Enclose your chatbox inside this container -->
Hello Frnd!
</div>
```

Result: [This is how it will look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9SSL.png)

Note: $.ajax sends request via a server. That's why you'll require to run this code through the server. Just opening the HTML will not work, CORS will produce some error.